# iconos con fontawesome no cargan los estilos css en navegadores android

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3, modernizr

Tengo estos iconos que en pc se ven bien pero en android no me cogen los estilos. también una imagen en parallax no aparece y el menú no aparece, estoy usando modernizr y no se si el fallo esta aquí o en js....

la consola me dice esto.

Este sitio parece usar un efecto de posicionamiento vinculado al desplazamiento. Esto puede no funcionar bien con panorámica asíncrona;

accediendo con mi ip publica me da este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
    
        
            CONTACTO
            ww@IGN.COM

```
        <p class="text-center redes">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x ikon">
                    <span class="htxt">Twitter</span>
                </i>
            </a>



            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x ikon">
                    <span class="htxt">Twitter</span>
                </i>
            </a>

        </p>
    </div>



#contact  a {
  background: #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  -moz-transition: background-color .5s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease;
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
  width: 60px; }
```

Comment: existe una comunidad específica para Android, tal vez allí pueden ayudarte mejor y antes: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, si en problema es visual, puedes adjungar pantallazos del error, cuando lo pruebas en android estas abriendo usando la IP de tu maquina donde tienes corriendo la app? si es asi es probable que tus assets no esten siendo compartidos. Tampoco mencionas si lo tienes corriendo bajo un servidor tipo NODEJS o solamente es un html. Tambien puedes usar el Chrome Developer tools con el chrome de tu Android y asi te aseguras si en realidad estas cargando FontAwesome o quizas es un problema de hidden en tu CSS. [Depurar App con el Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?hl=es)

Comment: no me permite conectar el portatil con el smartphone para usar el chrome del portatil con mi movil, me dice conection refused. he seguido los pasos del tutorial de google. uso ubuntu

Comment: es solamente html, css y js. he intentado depurar la web con el chrome dev tools pero me dice conexion refused. uso xubuntu.

Comment: el error 404 te sale porque no encuentra el recurso, y como estas accesando desde otro dominio que no es localhost pues te lo impide, para hacerlo una rapida demo, descargate el http://brackets.io/ y le das click en el boton con forma de rayito, este te correra tu web como si estuviese en un servidor local. si estas con el celular conectado al mismo WIFI, solo abrelo en tu celular usando la ip local de tu maquina y el puerto donde corre el app, me parece que brackets lo corre en el 8080.